# Is discrete reading in neural turing machines differentiable?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

For a neural turing machine, there is an attention distribution over the memory cells. A read operation consists of multiplying the memory cell's value by its respective probability, and adding these results for all memory cells.

Suppose we only did the above operation for memory cells with a probability greater than 0.5, or suppose we concatenated the results instead of adding them. Can this be implemented/ trained with stochastic gradient descent? Or would it not be differentiable?

Thanks!